# Okular documents clutter Ubuntu 18 dock

Tags: unity, firefox, kde, pdf

I use Okular to view PDF documents on Ubuntu 18.04. If I have multiple PDFs open at the same time, each of them creates a new item in the Ubuntu Dock.
This quickly messes up my dock. In addition, there is no preview available. I often end up ALT + TAB'ing into many of the documents first before I find the one that I want to look at.

All other applications that I regularly use are grouped automatically. If, for example, I have two Firefox windows open at the same time, they are grouped together in the dock and in the Alt + TAB switch panel. There is also a preview shown for each Firefox window. This makes it easy to select the desired window quickly.

**My question**: Is there an option to tell Ubuntu that it should group Okular documents in the same way as Firefox and basically everything else?

Comment: I would thing it is something to do with Okular not Ubuntu. Does it have any settings? You may want to have a look at their site. https://okular.kde.org/formats.php

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can see, Okular has an option for opening documents in tabs, instead of opening a new window. This is the opposite of what I want. Unfortunately, I don't even know the technical terms to describe or search for my desired behavior.  I contacted the forum because I was hoping for an explanation by somebody knowledgeable about the underlying intricacies between Ubuntu and Kde.

Comment: Someone might still answer.